# ASP.NET MVC Error Cannot implicitly convert type datamodel to entity

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

I´m making a weather app in ASP.NET MVC and I get errors that I can´t solve.
First error:

> Cannot implicitly convert type
>   `System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<WeatherService.Domain.Entities.Location>`
>   to
>   `System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<WeatherService.Domain.DataModels.Location>`.
>   An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

```
_geoNameWebservice.GetLocation(locationName);
```

Second error:

> Cannot implicitly convert type
>   `System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<WeatherService.Domain.DataModels.Location>`
>   to
>   `System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<WeatherService.Domain.Entities.Location>`.
>   An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

```
return locations;
```

Code:

```
public override IEnumerable<Location> GetLocation(string locationName)
{
    var locations = _iWeatherRepository.FindLocationByName(locationName);

    if (locations == null || locations.Count() == 0)
    {
        locations = _geoNameWebservice.GetLocation(locationName); 

        foreach (var location in locations)
        {
            _iWeatherRepository.AddLocation(location);
        }
        _iWeatherRepository.Save();
    }

    return locations;
}
```

What cast am I missing?

Comment: You are getting those errors because the types don't match.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting those errors because the types don't match.

first thing. You are setting `locations` as a `var.`

Unless `_iWeatherRepository.FindLocationByName(locationName);` and `_geoNameWebservice.GetLocation(locationName);` both return the same type then you cannot set both to `locations` if its type is implied.

`_geoNameWebservice.GetLocation(locationName)` returns `System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<WeatherService.Domain.Entities.Location>` so you will need to convert/map its items to match the intended type.

The first error implies that `_iWeatherRepository.FindLocationByName(locationName)` returns `System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<WeatherService.Domain.DataModels.Location>.`

the second error implies that the return type of the method is `System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<WeatherService.Domain.Entities.Location>`

you will need to explicitly state the types you are return to avoid confusing the compiler.

```
public override IEnumerable<WeatherService.Domain.DataModels.Location> GetLocation(string locationName)
{
    IEnumerable<WeatherService.Domain.DataModels.Location> locations = _iWeatherRepository.FindLocationByName(locationName);

    if (locations == null || locations.Count() == 0)
    {
        var entities = _geoNameWebservice.GetLocation(locationName); 

        foreach (var entity in entities)
        {
            var location = new WeatherService.Domain.DataModels.Location();
            //Copy the properties over to your domain model
            location.Property1 = entity.Property1;
            //...code removed for brevity

            _iWeatherRepository.AddLocation(location);
        }
        _iWeatherRepository.Save();
        locations = _iWeatherRepository.FindLocationByName(locationName)
    }

    return locations;
}
```

You can use something like **AutoMapper** to map the properties of your entity to your domain model.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Really feeling stupid though...I just dont understand why I have to state the types? The two location-classes are partial classes (of the same class); the entity.location is my model and the datamodel.location is the one entity framework creates. Shouldn´t the framework know that?

Comment: The two location classes are in different namespaces. That's why.